# Is there a way to tell if a page opened with Mechanize isn't returning "search results"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am using Mechanize to log in to a web site and make a search.  After extracting the links/info I want, I then recurisively move from the current page to the next to the next page.  What I'm wondering is if there's an easy way to tell -- based on header information, for instance -- if there are "No results found" or similar page.  If so, I could quickly check the header for a "404" or no-results page and then return.

I couldn't find it in the documentation and from what I can tell the answer is no.  Can anyone here say more definitely, tho, whether the answer is in fact no??  Thanks in advance.

(Presently I just do a .find() for 'no results' after I .read() the link.)

NOTES:

1) Header Info for a "good" page (with results):

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2013 18:33:10 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: close
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Status: 200 OK
header: X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
header: Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
header: X-Request-Id: b501064808b265fc6e478fa88e622710
header: X-Runtime: 0.478829
header: X-Rack-Cache: miss
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
```

2) Header Info from a "bad" (no results page)

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2013 18:33:11 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: close
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Status: 200 OK
header: X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
header: Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
header: X-Request-Id: 1ae89b2b25ba7983f8a48fa17f7a1798
header: X-Runtime: 0.127865
header: X-Rack-Cache: miss
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response header is generated by the server, you could add your own "no results" parameter and parse that...otherwise you have to analyze the content.

If you're set on using the header the only thing I can see between the two is that the bad search returned 4x faster -- maybe you could find a moving average for elapsed response times.